# How to set up mailboxes or mail forwarding for IIS SMTP?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-6, smtp

I've got a Windows 2008 R2 Server with IIS7, and the A record of my domain (mydomain.com) is pointing to my server.
Now, my users don't need their own mailboxes set up; they just need email forwarding so that bob@mydomain.com will forward to robert@anotherdomain.com, for example.  But for the life of me, I have no idea how to set that up!

Firstly, I installed SMTP Server, but couldn't find any SMTP server interface in IIS7.  After googling about that, it seems that you have to do SMTP management through an IIS6 interface!  Is that really true?  I find that difficult to believe - why would Microsoft have made you split your IIS management over 2 versions pf the same product?

Secondly, I've looked high and low for any kind of mailbox management options... couldn't find a thing.  Is it hiding somewhere?  Or do you have to buy or install some additional tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the split management is because the SMTP service is now part of the Exchange team's responsibilities whereas it used to be under the IIS team at Microsoft.  IIS6 is the only way that I know of to manage the SMTP service.  Here's a bit of info for you (specifically Wendy Henry's post): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/servervirtualization/thread/af4a8a7c-8d6d-4300-ba7f-e8cd0bcf431f

You will not be able to forward specific e-mail addresses out to another email address with Windows SMTP service.  Furthermore, if you wanted to run POP3 email on your Windows 2008 server, you're out of luck since they removed the native POP3 service capability.  There is also no IMAP.